# What are the high pranic foods according to Yogic culture?

Tags: yoga, food, yogi, sadhguru-jaggi-vasudev, prana

In the following video Sadhguru says Ash Gourd known as Kooshmanda. He says that is a high pranic food. That is why it is also used in sacrifices where they break it by throwing it to ground.

https://youtu.be/BQB149EEXkY

What are the other high pranic foods according to yogic culture or ancient Hindu scriptires? Is this somehow related to breaking of coconuts?

Please note: High pranic food should not be confused with Sattvik food. As it may or may bktbe same. If it is same plase give reference for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to your question. Some high positive Pranic foods are ALL fresh fruits and vegetables (expect onions and garlic of course), along with nuts, dairy products(except eggs). A very important part of the Pranic diet is herbal teas. Along with sweet spices such as cinnamon, cardamon, mint, basil, turmeric, ginger, cumin, and fennel seeds. And finally we some plant based oils such as sesame, sunflower, and olive oil. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Please edit and add proper citation to support your claim.

Comment: Where did you come to know about this?? Can you cite some sources.

Comment: Here are some of my sources: https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/pranic-food https://positivepranic.com/energy-diet-positive-pranic-food-list/ https://blendofbites.com/positive-pranic-food/